# Writing beta function in terms of gamma functions (by substitution)

Tags: integration, gamma-function, beta-function

I'm going over my notes and trying to write the Beta function in terms of gamma functions. However, I just can't get $(1.73)$ from $(1.72)$.

[image]

Even if I substitute $t/(1-t)$ with $u$, I can't remove $t$. Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $u = \frac{t}{1-t}$, then $u(1-t)=t$, that is, $$\begin{align*} u-ut &=t \\ \Rightarrow u &= ut+t \\ \Rightarrow u &=t(1+u).\end{align*}$$ So $t= \frac{u}{1+u}$. Try substituting this now.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!